# 401 Unauthorized Error when trying to read corporative emails in Gsuite from a Gmail account using Account Service

Tags: api, gmail, key, gmail-api, google-workspace

I´m having a problem to read emails in a corporative Gmail account, specifically a Gsuite Gmail account.

I followed this steps already:

- Go to the Google API Console.
- Create a new Project.
- Create a new Service Account
- Get the private key in p12 format
- Allow G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority to the Service Account.
- Go to the Gsuite Admin Panel.
- Go to the Security Section
- Allow the Email Scope(Read/Write/Send)  https://mail.google.com/ to the Service Account.
- I made the following code: (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation) using the private p12 key.
  Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/sebastianmorenoe/40c16c1bb3420b27917d2dc58eb385f0

Unfortunately I'm receiving this error: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

Thank you very much for any help that you can provide.

Greetings

Comment: What happens if you use the service account's email for the variable ACCOUNT_EMAIL instead of your own email?

Comment: @noogui it was a problem with the version of the maven dependencies. I post an answer with the correct dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the maven dependencies.

Using these dependencies solved the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev73-1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```